# Why don't dragons walk like other lizards?

Tags: history-of, dragons

I just occurred to me that, in all fiction that I can think of, dragons don't move like other lizards. I want to clarify that I'm talking about more traditional 4-legged dragons and not 2-legged ones (or wyverns), which you do see walking more like a bat which makes sense (*Smaug*, *The Hobbit* films).

Besides the obvious characterisation in some settings (*How to train your dragon*, for example), I don't recall ever seeing or reading about a dragon that moves like lizard (monitor lizard for example).

Have dragons always been like this? Was there a turning point where dragons starting being represented more upright with their legs underneath them (as opposed to the coming-out-the-side legs other lizard have)?

P.S. I looked through the list of SEs and thought that this was the right exchange for this question; Feel free to point me elsewhere.

Comment: This seems very broad. Also, monitor lizards look thoroughly stupid when running; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRG5oT7Ds0k which might explain it

Comment: I figured it might be a bit broad for StackExchange; Not to worry, I'll find somewhere better to post it.
Monitors look a little less stupid when they're bigger (Komodo Dragons), but I see your point.

Comment: What do you mean by asking why dragons don't walk lie "other" lizards?  Why do you assume that dragons are lizards?

Comment: I don't believe there are any vertebrates with six limbs like those kinds of dragons. (Though I'm not a biologist.)

Comment: Dragons aren't lizards, and there is no reason for them to move similarly. If you want to assign them a real life category, it likely would not get much narrower than *reptile* - an extremely wide category that includes snakes, turtles, birds (yep!), dinosaurs, etc - a whole lot of animals with all sorts of methods of locomotion.

Comment: Not really adding anything of note here, but during the development of Dragon Age: Inquisition, they based the movements of the dragons off of cats. If you try to fight one, they really captured the movement of the cats quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by asking why dragons don't walk like "other" lizards? Why do you assume that dragons are lizards?

Lizards are a subcategory of reptiles.  Are dragons even reptiles?

That is what this question asks:  [Is Smaug a reptile?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170057/is-smaug-a-reptile)[1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170057/is-smaug-a-reptile)

What do Tolkien's dragons themselves think about the subject of their relationship to lizards?  I can quote Smaug:

> Lake-men, some nasty scheme of those miserable tub-trading Lake-men, or I’m a lizard.
>   <sub>The Hobbit - Chapter 12, Inside Information</sub>

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question.